# Thinking logically: Calculate how many times a certain number appears in an integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, logic, modulo

Going through a self-learn book they gave you some code to find how many times a specific digit is in an integer or not. How did they automatically know to use modulo 10? Is this something you as a programmer learn a trick for in your CompSci classes?

```
def num_zero_and_five_digits(n):
    count = 0
    while n:
        digit = n % 10 # This divides w/10 for remainder. How did they know to use 10?
        if digit == 0 or digit == 5: #These can be changed to whatever digits you want.
            count = count + 1
            n = n / 10 
    return count
```

I *understand* the code, but don't own it. What I mean is that if I was asked to 'write code' that would find how many times a certain digit is in an integer, I would personally 
do something like this:

```
integer = str(22342445)
looker = list(integer)
counter = 0
find = raw_input("What number are you looking for")
for num in looker:
    if find == num:
        print "We found it!"
        counter += 1

print "There are %d, %s's in %s" % (counter, find,integer )
```

Now, my main questions are:

1. What if someone wants to look for the integer "10" or higher? How
   can I account for that in the first solution?
2. What steps would you  personally take to come up with a solution like the first? How would you just "know" that you needed to do modulo 10?

Comment: This is too broad, possibly should also be moved to math SO and is also looking for external resource. You really should break it down into multiple separate questions.

Comment: I will cut it down a little bit, to make it less broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exercise itself is improperly defined. Rather than looking for a specific number it should instead ask about looking for a specific *numeral*. This restricts it to, since we use decimal (base-10) numbers (by which I mean that we use the base-10 representation of numbers), one of 10 possibilities. And since we use base-10 numbers, we need to divide by and take the modulus of 10 to separate the number into its digits so that we can compare the numerals. If we were talking about a hexadecimal number instead then we would use 16 to separate the digits, for octal we would use 8, etc.

Comment: So this essentially means that because we are using base 10, we cannot 'find" any digits more than 1-9.
  So there is no way to count for how many 10s, 21s, 22s etc?

Comment: You can find pairs of numerals from 0-9, but you would not do it in the same way.

Comment: How would I go about that? A hint is fine. I tried switching to % 100, which could return two digits, but no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: Using a modulus that covers two positions will check every *other* pair. You should switch to string searching in this case to keep the solution simple.

Comment: I appreciate it, so in fact my answer would be closest to a correct solution. Thank you!